# Как вывести счетчик в одном сообщении в чат-боте Telegram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Мне нужно отправить сообщение именно с помощью post запроса.

**Ошибка:**
request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'end'

Какие могут быть альтернативные решения? В гугле не нашла ... (

```
def post_iterator(sec, chat_id):
    try:
        for i in range(sec, 0, -1):
            # print(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=i)), end = '\r')
            requests.post(f'{URL}/sendMessage', data = {'chat_id': chat_id,
                'text': f'{str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=i))}'}, end = '\r')
            time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

**Без аргумента 'end':**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали убирать этот параметр end?

Comment: Да, тогда счетчик в разные сообщения...

Comment: Что означает "тогда счетчик в разные сообщения..."?

Comment: Гыыыыыыыыыы. Сейчас вопрос обновлю

Comment: Если вам нужно изменять счетчик в существующем сообщении, то нужно использовать редактирование сообщения, а не отправку нового. Параметр `end='\r'` будет работать только в функции print в консоли.

Comment: Знаю. Но почему не возможно сделать аналогичное с помощью post запроса? Может альтернатива есть...

Comment: Очевидно, потому что пост-запрос - это не print, и телеграм-бот - не консоль.

Comment: да и это мне понятно, но как тогда можно решить.. не имеет значение, что это, как-то можно решить, но я пока не понимаю что можно придумать.. спасибо.

Comment: Используйте [editMessageText](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#editmessagetext) в post-запросе для изменения текста сообщения.

Comment: Точно! Попробую, отпишусь

Comment: Я не понимаю как достать message_id (((

Comment: mess = requests.post(f'{URL}/sendMessage', data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': f'{str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec))}'})
        for i in range(sec, 0, -1):
            requests.post(f'{URL}/editMessageText', data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message_id': ?,
                'text': f'{str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=i))}'})
            time.sleep(1)

Comment: Первым пост запросом через sendMessage отправляете сообщение, в ответ приходит json с объектом сообщения. Из него достаете id сообщения. Дальше по этому id сообщения редактируете его.

Comment: Поняла, mess.json()

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Получилось))

Answer (score 1):

**Решение (благодаря пользователю insolor):**

```
def post_iterator(sec, chat_id, mess_id):
    mess = requests.post(f'{URL}/sendMessage', data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': f'{str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec))}'}).json()
    for i in range(sec, 0, -1):
        # print(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=i)), end = '\r')
        requests.post(f'{URL}/editMessageText', data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message_id': mess['result']['message_id'],
            'text': f'{str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=i))}'})
        time.sleep(1)
```